# Make a flutter application with webview + beacon

Tags: flutter, beacon, flutterwebviewplugin

I'd like to make an application with flutter.
I already publised all of the pages, and i want to use this in flutter webview.

Here's the difficult part, I'd like to apply a beacon scanning to this flutter webview application.

If the application scans a beacon, I want to show the corresponding page that connected with beacon.

*[Edit] The only information i need from a beacon is its UUID.*

Is it possible to make an application like this?

I am now trying to make it for both android and ios, of course, but it would be perfectly OK if the answer is for andriod (or ios) only.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what should happen to a scanning result (stream of beacons)? The result should be available for javascript?

Comment: Yes. The scanning UUID should be available for javascirpt to call API